# Keep only non missing consecutive values in R grouped data

Tags: r, dplyr

I have the following dataset:

```
structure(list(ISIN = c("AEA000201011", "AEA000201011", "AEA000201011", 
"AEA000201011", "AEA000201011", "AEA000201011", "AEA000201011", 
"AEA000201011", "AEA000201011", "AEA000201011", "AEA000801018", 
"AEA000801018", "AEA000801018", "AEA000801018", "AEA000801018", 
"AEA000801018", "AEA000801018", "AEA000801018", "AEA000801018", 
"AEA000801018", "AEA001501013", "AEA001501013", "AEA001501013", 
"AEA001501013", "AEA001501013", "AEA001501013", "AEA001501013", 
"AEA001501013", "AEA001501013", "AEA001501013"), year = c(2010L, 
2011L, 2012L, 2013L, 2014L, 2015L, 2016L, 2017L, 2018L, 2019L, 
2010L, 2011L, 2012L, 2013L, 2014L, 2015L, 2016L, 2017L, 2018L, 
2019L, 2010L, 2011L, 2012L, 2013L, 2014L, 2015L, 2016L, 2017L, 
2018L, 2019L), refin_esg = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, 48.74, 54.32, 63.81, 
67.64, 71.74, 68.17, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 30.89, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, 13.47, 14.63, 19.68, 17.51, 13.92, 15.15), refin_e = c(NA, 
NA, NA, NA, 23.21, 53.02, 60.18, 18.64, 50.25, 52.21, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 20.52, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0), mktcap = c(2723907, 4219977, 4576565, 9207428, 9954352, 
9329029, 9765366, 9623839, 11548606, 15002191, 1918568, 2047331, 
2047331, 3734126, 4655646, 3399201, 3277575, 3260324, 3856508, 
5329892, 641477, 647176, 957332, 2452771, 3505987, 1571026, 1646012, 
971968, 775941, 526823)), class = c("grouped_df", "tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -30L), groups = structure(list(
    ISIN = c("AEA000201011", "AEA000801018", "AEA001501013"), 
    .rows = structure(list(1:10, 11:20, 21:30), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", 
    "vctrs_vctr", "list"))), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), .drop = TRUE))
```

I only want to keep those ISINs (group ID) which have at least 3 consecutive non-NA values. For example, if an ISIN only has two non-NA years, then the whole ISIN gets dropped. Similarly, if an ISIN has 3 non NA years, but they are not consecutive, then that ISIN gets dropped as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we are interested in only the adjacent non-NA rows of length greater than 2 for each ISIN, grouped by ISIN, loop over the `refin` columns with `if_all`, return a single logical vector (i.e. non-NA - TRUE for all the refin columns for a row or else FALSE), then apply `rle` on the vector and check for the `lengths` of TRUE value to `filter`

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>% 
  group_by(ISIN) %>%
   filter( with(rle(if_all(starts_with('refin'), complete.cases)), 
      rep(values & lengths >2, lengths))) %>%
   ungroup
```

Or if we want the whole group having atleast one occurrence of non-NA adjacent elements > 2, wrap with `any` over the `rle` output

```
df1 %>% 
  group_by(ISIN) %>%
   filter( any(with(rle(if_all(starts_with('refin'), complete.cases)), 
      values & lengths >2))) %>%
   ungroup
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 20 × 5
   ISIN          year refin_esg refin_e   mktcap
   <chr>        <int>     <dbl>   <dbl>    <dbl>
 1 AEA000201011  2010      NA      NA    2723907
 2 AEA000201011  2011      NA      NA    4219977
 3 AEA000201011  2012      NA      NA    4576565
 4 AEA000201011  2013      NA      NA    9207428
 5 AEA000201011  2014      48.7    23.2  9954352
 6 AEA000201011  2015      54.3    53.0  9329029
 7 AEA000201011  2016      63.8    60.2  9765366
 8 AEA000201011  2017      67.6    18.6  9623839
 9 AEA000201011  2018      71.7    50.2 11548606
10 AEA000201011  2019      68.2    52.2 15002191
11 AEA001501013  2010      NA      NA     641477
12 AEA001501013  2011      NA      NA     647176
13 AEA001501013  2012      NA      NA     957332
14 AEA001501013  2013      NA      NA    2452771
15 AEA001501013  2014      13.5     0    3505987
16 AEA001501013  2015      14.6     0    1571026
17 AEA001501013  2016      19.7     0    1646012
18 AEA001501013  2017      17.5     0     971968
19 AEA001501013  2018      13.9     0     775941
20 AEA001501013  2019      15.2     0     526823
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, Akrun. Follow up question: What if I just want to keep the IDs where there are 3 or more non-missing values (i.e., we remove the consecutive condition). So any ISIN that has less than 2 non missing values gets dropped.